# Inexpensive do-it-yourself Steadicam rig

Tags: video

Anyone have experience with a cheap DIY Steadicam style rig for a video camera? It doesn't have to take perfect picture, but be steadier than a handheld camera. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is enough for you?

Basically just use a tripod as a balance and let gravity do the job for you.

Comment: A follow-up, @AlexanderBrevig. What's the next step up from this?

Comment: Maybe use a gyroscopic balance where you'd want it? I think mechanical correction is easier for DIY than programming it (if you have some know how about that you could check out PID loops and sensor fusion). If you've ever used a power tool equipped with a large plate (for grinding, for instance) you know about the force I'm talking about. I've never tried to make anything like this. Is there no project online? Check instructables first :)

Comment: @Alex - the next step would be to add a gymbal on the balance to make it so that it can rotate freely. This is the concept behind a steadycam jr.  You basically want a shaft with a mounting plate on one end and a counterweight on the other with a frictionless gymbal slightly closer to the mount than the weight.  The next step up from that is either to add a gyroscope that will actually fight to keep orientation rather than just using inertia to do it or to add a spring arm that mounts to a chest rig to take your arms out of the equation.